# Multiple Points Along Line between two known Geo Coords?

Tags: java, geo, coords

I have a Java project to plot properties to geo co-ords. It does not need to be super accurate, within 10+ metres is fine.

I have searched Haversine formulas, and midpoint formulas, but I can't see how they solve my problem:

I have a set of coords for corner and end lot properties. I know that there are for example, 6 properties between these two known points.

I am no maths or GIS expert, so I wanted an informed opinion if the following strategy si workable or rubbish:

Take the difference between LAT and LNG A and B. Divide that number by the number or properties. Will this work, or is there a better way of doing this?

Your answer is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formulae from spherical geometry as they are presented e.g. in [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). In the following I will refer to this page.

1. Calculate the bearing `theta` between the two given points `P1` and `P2` (use formula for **Bearing**).
2. Calculate the distance `d` between the two given points  `P1` and `P2` (use formula for **Distance**).
3. Calculate any point `P` on the line between  `P1` and `P2`, given the distance `D` from `P1`, in your case `D = d/6, D = 2d/6, ...` Use the formula under **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point**.

ADDED: A running JS program with source code is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLrwD/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it confirms my basic idea, even if I didn't have the maths skills to describe it. I'd seen the Moveable Type article before but wasn't completely sure it was the answer. Thanks. I'll fiddle with this and see how I go.

Comment: Hi Jiri, thanks for your answer, but I'm still unclear what do you mean by 'theta' and how do I calculate it? What are the steps to work this out? Thanks for your advice so far.

Comment: @Anthony: `theta` (greek letter) is the bearing in the formula for bearing on the mentioned page. I added a Javascript [program with source code](http://jsfiddle.net/wLrwD/). I know, you need it in Java, but it is easy to transport the formulae to Java.

Comment: This solution was exactly what I needed. I've implemented it in Java and it works like a dream. Thanks for saving my sanity, my hair and redecorating my wall after banging my head against it.